# Cefsharp not rendering properly

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have embed `CefSharp` in my application using C# but looks like browser rendering is not proper (screenshot is attached below). I tried to find the issue without a success.

This is how I am initializing `CEF` :

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    InitializeChromium();
}
public void InitializeChromium() {
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");
    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
}
```

[Error picture 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPh9p.png)

I want to know why this is happening?, thank you.

Comment: Please show us the code in `InitializeComponent`

Comment: This is possibly caused by DPI settings greater than 100%. Try:

`CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("force-device-scale-factor", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);`

Comment: Thank you very much, my dpi is set to 125%. When I set to 100% on the normal display.